# Report alerts still sending after alert and report was deleted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report in SharePoint 2010, there was an alert set to send every minute regardless of whether the data changed. This alert was deleted, then the report was deleted, but its still sending the email. After the report was deleted it was still emailing the alert but the email contained an error message saying that the report cannot be found and not the actual report.

I have checked the `User Alerts` under `Site Admin` and `Manage Data Alerts` in `Reporting Services`,  both are empty. I have checked the alerts for the specific report as well.

Is there any way of stopping this?

**UPDATE

> It seems that alerts don't work as I expected them to.
>
> When an alert is triggered it writes a record to a log, it is not sent immediately. The job that sends the email alerts runs periodically, every 5 minutes by default, and picks up all the alerts that need to be sent and sends them.
> As the alert was created about 2 months ago so there is approx 90,000 emails in the log waiting to be sent so until this clears the emails will continue to be sent.
>
> The article [The truth about how daily SharePoint alerts actually work](http://www.chrisdomino.com/blog/post/The-Truth-About-How-Daily-SharePoint-Alerts-Actually-Work) by Chris Domino describes this pretty well

So now my question is how to clear the "log"?

Comment: When it sends you the email, does it come with a link to manage the alerts on this page/list/report? Or is that where you originally deleted the alert from?

Comment: No the only link is to the report on the site

Comment: uhhh...this is a tough one. Did you possibly check Site Settings > Site Administration> User Alerts and make sure that is clear?

Comment: I have checked both the user alerts and the manage data alerts, I am fairly certain that the alert is deleted completely, What the problem now is that the alert was created a couple of months ago so there is approx 100,000 alerts in the "log" waiting to be sent, so it will continue to send the alerts until this is clear